# cosine similarity of 2 arraylist in java

Tags: java, casting, double, information-retrieval, dot-product

I have 2 files containing the weights of terms, my objectif is to calculate the cosine similarity 
cos =  dotproduct ( weight1 ,weights2) / euclidianDistance( weight1 )* euclidianDistance (weight2));

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class tp5
{
    private static BufferedReader br1;
    private static BufferedReader br2;

    public static double getSimilarity(File file1, File file2)
        throws IOException
    {
        br1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file1));
        String line1;
        line1 = br1.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> words1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String word : line1.split(" ")) {
            words1.add(word);
        }

        br2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file2));
        String line2;
        line2 = br2.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> words2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String word : line2.split(" ")) {
            words2.add(word);
        }

        int i;
        int j;
        int k;

        //  Double [] temp = null;
        Double DotProduct = (double) 0 ;
        Double euclid1 = (double) 0;
        Double euclid2 = (double) 0; 

        for (j = 0; j < words1.size(); j++) {
            DotProduct += Double.parseDouble(words1.get(j)) * Double.parseDouble(words2.get(j));
        }

        for (i = 0; i < words1.size(); i++) {
            euclid1 = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(words1.get(i)), Double.parseDouble(words1.get(i)));
        }

        euclid1 = Math.sqrt(euclid1);

        for (k = 0; k < words1.size(); k++) {
            euclid2 = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(words2.get(k)), Double.parseDouble(words2.get(k)));
        }

        euclid2 = Math.sqrt(euclid2);

        return DotProduct / (euclid1 * euclid2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException
    {
        File file1 = new File("texte.95-1.poids");
        File file2 = new File("texte.95-2.poids");

        System.out.println(getSimilarity(file1, file2));
    }
}
```

The problem that my weights can be like this for example weight = 0.750305594399894

I have an error in `Double.parseDouble`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""    0.750305594399894"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
```

What is the solution?

Comment: The problem is, that the program wants to make a double out of "" (like the Exception tells you). So you are probably reading an empty line or something (at some point, the String in Double.parseDouble(String) is empty).

Comment: @ThomasBöhm sorry i don't understand you what do you propose to me it s ambiguous for me

Answer (score 0):

The thrown exception `NumberFormatException` happens when you try to parse String to a number, but that number is baldy written. Probably because of a comma (try a dot), because it's an empty String, or because there is a letter.

I hope I have helped.

Have a nice day. :)

Comment: thank you for answer but i think the problem is not in the comma because already i have a dot

Comment: post you tests and results to see clearly what you are inputting.

Comment: the test is the public static void main and the results is the error mentioned

Comment: In the method you ask for an input from a file. Just copy-past a bit of that file.

Comment: this is  a part of my file  0.750305594399894
1.6863989535702288
3.9889840465642745
0.14085438483348112 
0.15096131193138845
2.8903717578961645
3.9889840465642745
2.7362210780689065
7.16703787691222
4.68213122712422
2.379546134130174
0.6253667493143963
2.6026896854443837
4.68213122712422    i have changed the code and i have a new error you can check the new code and the new error

Comment: `split( String regex )` it's a very good method, however if you have more that one space between the numbers it can create an empty `String`. Try to check in the for loop if it's an empty `String`.

Comment: for (String word : line1.split(" ")) {
    if( !word.isEmpty() )
        words1.add(word);
}

Answer (score 0):

Just used Double.valueOf(String number) and didn't have a problem with your test cases.